# DataBinding asp.net DropDownList from a List of ListItems causing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I am attempting to DataBind an asp:DropDownList with a Collections.Generic.List of System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItems. The DataBind() is throwing this error.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'ddlPlatinumOptions' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

.ascx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPlatinumOptions" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
```

.ascx.cs

```
public void BindPlatinumOptions()
{
    ddlPlatinumOptions.DataTextField = "Text";
    ddlPlatinumOptions.DataValueField = "Value";
    ddlPlatinumOptions.DataSource = _platinumOptions;
    ddlPlatinumOptions.DataBind(); // Throwing Error
}
```

presenter

```
MattressProtectionInfo standard = RF_ProtectionPlan.GetMattressPlanInfo(MattressId, false);
MattressProtectionInfo premium = RF_ProtectionPlan.GetMattressPlanInfo(MattressId, true);
List<ListItem> plans = new List<ListItem>();                  
if (standard != null)
{
    plans.Add(new ListItem(standard.Price.ToString("C") + " - Standard 5-Year Platinum Protection", standard.ProductID.ToString()));
}
if (premium != null)
{
    plans.Add(new ListItem(premium.Price.ToString("C") + " - Premium 5-Year Platinum Protection", premium.ProductID.ToString()));
}

_view.PlatinumOptions = plans;
_view.BindPlatinumOptions();
```

Data Example

- Value = "21696" Text = "$99.95 - Standard 5-Year Platinum Protection"
- Value = "21702" Text = "$119.95 - Premium 5-Year Platinum Protection"

Thing I have tried

- Nulling datasource and Databinding before my data to clear out anything (broke on dataBind as well)
- relocating position of DataTextField and DataValueField (waste of time - no change)
- declaring a selected index of 0 before the databind
- ddlPlatinumOptions.Items.Clear();
- ddlPlatinumOptions.ClearSelection();

I am grabbing at straws. It appears as if the databind is trying to select something inside of the dropdownlist that isn't there.

Is there an error in my code I'm not seeing? Any Ideas?

Comment: instead of Binding ..why don't you add the items to the `DropDownList` directly.. if that's not an option then take a look here this should help solve your issue `Ryan O'Hara` [How to populate DropDownList using List<ListItem>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864880/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-using-a-listlistitem)

Comment: I am already building my ListItem like there are in that answer. The problem appears to be with-in the asp.net DropDownList.DataBind(). It appears to be trying to select a value that is not bound yet?
If I wrap the BindPlatinumOptions() in a try catch and swallow the error the ListItem are still rendered to the page and work fine. I want to know why it is throwing this error, but I can't seam to find the source code for the asp.net Databind method for asp 3.5

Comment: well what event is it being triggered from.. is this happening on `Load` or during a PostBack.. also I think that you can bind directly as I have mentioned without using a List<Item> for example where are you getting the data from or reading it from in regards to loading the ddl..? I think there is a simpler approach

Comment: I am binding it on ViewLoad, I am building the list<ListItem> in the presenter not hard coding them on the view.

Comment: I do not think that you are understanding anyway checkout that link that was posted in my previous / earlier comment you are obviously doing something wrong and I was not talking about hard coding btw

Comment: Thank you, but I do understand. Setting the DataTextField and DataValueField in the code behind or markup will not make a difference as long as in the code behind, it is set before the DataBind() method is called. We use an MVP architecture, so all logic processing is done in the presenter. We also like to keep as much in code as possible so we use .DataTextField, .DataValueField, and .DataBind() in the code behind throughout our site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's an out of range exception.. Are you setting the SelectedIndex to a default value at any point before you are binding to the DropDownList?

Comment: This should probably be more of a comment

Answer (score 7):

After facing this problem, too, I debugged the ASP.NET source code and found a flaw(?) in the ASP.NET source code (and, hence, the solution to our problem):

Internally, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Listcontrol` caches the most recently used `SelectedValue`. So when a data binding occurs (which natively clears the `SelectedValue` property) after the `SelectedValue` has already been set from `Request.Form[]`, the data binding operation tries to find and pre-select the previously cached item. Unfortunately it throws an exception when the cached value isn't found in the new `DataSource` list instead of silently leaving the current `SelectedValue` `null` value alone.

I guess they did that because when using `ViewState` *and* data source objects for data binding, the later data bind operation would remove the `SelectedValue` obtained by `Request.Form[]`.

So, whenever you perform more than one data binding operation on a `ListControl` within a page lifecycle and when the data sources differ, then this exception occurs.

### Here's the ASP.NET code synopsis:

```
    public virtual string SelectedValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (Items.Count != 0)
            {
                // at design time, a binding on SelectedValue will be reset to the default value on OnComponentChanged
                if (value == null || (DesignMode && value.Length == 0))
                {
                    ClearSelection();
                    return;
                    // !!! cachedSelectedValue is not getting reset here !!!
                }

            ...

            // always save the selectedvalue
            // for later databinding in case we have viewstate items or static items
            cachedSelectedValue = value;
        }
    }
```

### And here's the solution:

Instead of:

```
    dropDownBox.DataSource = ...;
    dropDownBox.DataBind();
```

Write this:

```
    dropDownBox.Items.Clear();
    dropDownBox.SelectedValue = null;
    dropDownBox.DataSource = ...;
    dropDownBox.DataBind();
```

(The `dropDownBox.Items.Clear();` operation is only required if `dropDownBox.Items` isn't already empty.)