# How can I dynamically populate listview edit template listitem values (asp)?

Tags: html, asp.net, listview

I want to be able to populate the 3 list items below dynamically from a web.config file, how can I do that in my c# code behind instead of having them hard coded in the html code?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
     <tr style="">
          <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="component" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# Bind("component") %>' >
                            <asp:ListItem>Choose a component</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Component1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Component2</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
     </tr>
</EditItemTemplate>


 protected void lvwOutput_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string stop = "here";

        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            // what can I do here?
        }

}
```

Comment: Is that item count is fixed?

Comment: No, the listitem count isn't fixed. I want to be able to add and subtract items in the web.config. There may be 50 items in there, there may be 5 items. I can read the web.config, but I don't know how to populate the edit template and google hasn't been any help?

Comment: Are you using GridView?

Comment: Take a look at the link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I'm using listview,  and that looks very similar to what I have. I don't see anywhere where the programmer has a list that programmatically populates the edit template?

Comment: It looks like I can bind a separate datatable as in this example? I've tried to make it work but cannot figure it out?
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-ListView-EditItemTemplate-example-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: If it still not working then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4864880/7124761